# Get length of string using Vimscript

Tags: string, vim

This may be a very basic question, but I can't seem to find an answer with a simple Google search.

I simply want to find the length of a string using Vimscript, similar to len() function in Python. Is there a simple way to do this in Vimscript, or will I just have to loop over the string?

Comment: See here for a more complete answer: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/21086/18609

Comment: You might want to check out the [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) for questions on Vim!

Comment: `len()` will show the number of bytes in a string. Instead, we should use `strchars()` to get the string length properly. It seems weird, but that is how Vim works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is `len` and `strlen`. For strings they are same.

```
:echo len("Hello")
:echo strlen("Hello")
```

Comment: Depending on how you want to handle tabs, multi-byte and double width characters, you might also need `strchars()`, `strwidth()`, or `strdisplaywidth()`.  Also the result might depend on other settings, such as `ts` or encoding.

Comment: This answer is incomplete and does not work well for multi-byte characters!

Comment: @lcd047 Thank you!! It took me bloody ages to find `strdisplaywith()`!! You should really post this as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Note that the [answer by Ashwani](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57783471/6064933) only works for single-byte characters, not for multi-byte characters.**

There is function `strlen()` or `len()` in Vim, but they only calculates byte length of a string, instead of character length, like what `len()` function in Python does. We can instead use the [`strchars()`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/eval.html#strchars()) function to get
string length. I consider this one of the many hidden quirks of Vim. We just
need to get accustomed to it.